# What's the name of this oil trading board game?

Tags: identify-this-game, trading

When I was a child I used to play around with the figures of a game that a relative of mine had tucked away in his attic. It was some sort of oil trading board game and some of the components I remember playing with were:

1. Oil tanker minis
2. Spherical gas storage tank minis: [image: Gas Containers]
3. World map, very minimal graphic style
4. Paper money, like something out of an old Monopoly copy

Publishing Date: The game was possibly published in the 1970s / 80s
Visual Style: Quite minimal and somewhat bleak, a bit like Twilight Struggle

I was too young to figure out the rules or how to play the game, especially since it was in English and it isn't my mother tongue, however I had a lot of fun playing with the minis and from what I remember the game seemed quite complex and may be worth tracking down and playing it now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As usual, a specific year (or range) and country would be helpful.

Comment: Case in point, the suggestion below of **Wildcatters** would be precluded from consideration if we knew that this was before 2010.

Comment: Sorry, I would say the publishing date would have been in the 70s or 80s, I will add it to the post. Also the visual design was somewhat bleak, something in the lines of Twilight Struggle.

Comment: Just searching Oil on BoardGameGeek pulls up dozens of results, several of which are within the appropriate time frame, and many of which have pieces that might fit the description. @MACC If you find the answer yourself, it's totally acceptable to answer your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the game after discussing it with some fellow Portuguese gamers. It's actually a vintage Portuguese game about oil called "Petróleo": https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/22614/petroleo - Seems to be quite hard to find these days.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps ["Wildcatters"](https://www.capstone-games.com/wildcatters) as shown on the website of CapStone Games.

[This link](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/146910/wildcatters) is the game on BGG.

Oil tanker minis:

[image: Oil tanker minis]

Spherical gas storage tank minis:

[image: Spherical gas storage tank minis]

Comment: The gas storage minis were actually made of plastic and fairly detailed. I remember playing with them as a child.